# Eloquent: Difference between defining relations in model and in migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What is the difference between defining the relation between 2 tables within the two models and defining it in the proper migration file?

For example, I want a many to one relationship between the table `cars` and the table `persons`.

**Option 1: I define the relation in the models**

Model Person:

```
class Person extends Model
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
    }
}
```

Model Car:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Person');
    }
}
```

**Option 2: I define the relation in the migration**

```
class CreateCarsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('person_id')->references('id')->on('person');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cars');
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Second one is not a relationship it's called foreign key constraint

Comment: @MahdiYounesi What's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not the same thing.**

The `hasOne()`, `hasMany()`, `belongsToOne()` and `belongsToMany()` functions are merely query builders that return the results of a SQL query.

For example, the `cars()` method of the `Person` model with `id` is 1 in your example returns the results of the query `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE person_id=1`.

However, the foreign key has the same purpose than in a SQL script to create the `cars` table. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
    ...
    person_id INT REFRENCES person(id),
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

> Eloquent relationships are defined as methods on your Eloquent model classes. Since, like Eloquent models themselves, relationships also serve as powerful query builders, defining relationships as methods provides powerful method chaining and querying capabilities

What you mentioned about migrations is:

1.FOREIGN KEYS just ensure your data are consistent.

2. If we apply on delete cascade to the foreign key definition,referencing row will delete automatically when parent row will delete.
3. If we apply on Update Cascade to the foreign key definition,Child row will update automatically when parent row will update

Comment: I still don't see the connection very well. When I call the function `cars()` of the first Person model, it returns the results of the query `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE person_id=1` am I right?

Comment: Yes, so you're doing this using a helper instead of writing raw queries, that helper  function has provide a relationship between two models, but what you said about referencing foreign keys in migrations is not same a relationships in Laravel, Those defined in mysql are only for ensuring data consistent

Comment: Ok thank you, I upvoted your answer but I still don't find it very clear. I will write an answer in this thread and either you take elements from it in your answer and I validate yours, or I validate mine in 2 days.